# How to use substring in VBA ? (Convert a String to a decimal with substring)

Tags: vba, string, type-conversion, format

I tried to pull a String from a cell in an Excel table and convert it into a Double. Afterwards, I wanted to format the Double as a currency and remove the currency sign.

Unfortunately, I am always getting the error

> Run-time error 424: Object Required

```
Dim price_right_str As String
Dim price_right As Double


price_right_str = ActiveSheet.Cells(a, b_new).Value
price_right = CDbl(Val(price_right_str))
price_right_str = FormatCurrency(price_right, 2)
price_right_str = price.Substring(1, (Len(price_right_str) - 1))
```

I'd appreciate any proposal for a better solution. All I need is an output which is (theoretically) a price without the currency symbol.

Comment: 65
65,5

And i want something like : 65,00 ; 65,50

Comment: Try `preis_right_str = Format(ActiveSheet.Cells(a, b_new).Value,"0.00")`

Comment: You already solved my problem but i test that too

Comment: Ok that worked aswell thanks for your help ^^

Comment: @Z3RP please ask future questions in English otherwise they will be closed.

Comment: @CallumDA Ok no Problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA does not have String function called `SubString()`. Instead use `Right(str)`, `Mid(str)` or `Left(str)`.

As @YowE3K mentioned in the comments, this is the answer:
`price_right_str = Mid(price_right_str, 2)` or `price_right_str = Left(price_right_str, Len(price_right_str) - 1)`

Comment: Ich hatte vergessen zu schreiben das ich noch so eine Funktion erstellt habe
`Public Function Substring(startIndex As Integer, length As Integer) As String

End Function`

Comment: @Z3RP - Then use `Substring(1, (Len(preis_right_str) - 1))` not `preis.Substring(1, (Len(preis_right_str) - 1))`

Comment: @YowE3K How did the programm than know which string i want to use ?

Comment: @Z3RP - Ahh - What does the function do?  Please show the code.  Was macht die Funktion? Bitte geben Sie den Code an.

Comment: @Z3RP The program can't know it. You need another parameter in your SubString function: `Subtring(str as String, startIndex as Integer, length as Integer)`

Comment: @YowE3K This is the whole Function.
I got the Function form a website (i think msdn but i forgot it sry)

Comment: @Z3RP - That function doesn't do anything at all.  I think you just want to use `preis_right_str = Mid(preis_right_str, 2)` or `preis_right_str = Left(preis_right_str, Len(preis_right_str) - 1)`

Comment: @Qomaa did not work aswell the result is : " " (nothing)

Comment: @Z3RP - also try `preis_right_str = Format(ActiveSheet.Cells(a, b_new).Value,"0.00")`

Comment: @YowE3K and Qomaa please do not answer questions that are not in English - they shouldn't be translated either. See here: *[how do I deal with non-English content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content)*